# Extract dates times from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I have a dataset with some date time like this `"{datetime:2015-07-01 09:10:00"` So I wanted to remove the text, and then keep the date & the time as `as.Date` returns only the date. So I write this code but the only problem I have is that during the second line with strsplit, it only returns me the date time of the first line and so erase the others... I woud love to get ALL my date time not only the first. I thought about sapply maybe, but I can't make it right I have many errors or maybe with a loop for? I am novice to R so I don't really know how to do this the best way.

Could you help me please? Besides If you have another idea for the time & date format or a simple way to do it, it should be very nice of you too.

```
data$`Date Time`=as.character(data$`Date Time`)

data$`Date Time`=unlist(strsplit(data[,1], split='e:'))[2]

date=substr(data$`Date Time`,0,10)

date=as.Date(date)

time=substr(data$`Date Time`,12,19)

data$Date=date

data$Time=time
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(data[,1], "e:"), FUN = function(x) {x[2]})`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `format` argument to avoid all the strsplit:

```
times <- as.POSIXct(data$`Date Time`, format='{datetime:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

(The reason for the "{datetime:" in the format is because you mentioned this is the format of your strings).

This object has both date and time in it, and then you can just store it in the dataframe as a single column of type POSIXct rather than two columns of type string e.g.

```
data$datetime <- times
```

but if you do want to store the date as a Date and the time as a string (as in your example above):

```
data$Date <- as.Date(times)
data$Time <- strftime(times, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

See `?as.Date`, `?as.POSIXct`, `?strptime` for more details on that `format`  argument and various conversions between date and string.

Comment: Thank you very much !!
Besides it's only for a date but if I have the same problem with for example : "subject:MMM" how would you resolve this if I just want "MMM" because once again, with strsplit() I loose all the levels "MMM, ABC, JKL...", please?

Comment: Sorry, I found with this : 
data$Subject <- gsub("subject:", "", data$Subject) 
!!